# How to get commits from remote master to local branch

Tags: git

Before down voting or marking it as duplicate, let me explain the situation. I've a remote branch `qr-frontend` for which I have a local branch `qr-frontend`. I need to get all changes from master to the local `qr-frontend` branch. What I'm trying to do it to merge my branch with master remote and do a pull request.

I tried to do the following:

```
git checkout qr-frontend
git fetch origin 
git merge origin/master
```

but when I try the last command, I get a lot of conflicts on all files which I made changes after my last merge.

Can anyone help me with the correct flow? Also, how do I always keep my local branch updated with master remote?

Comment: This is normal, you have merge conflicts , which you need to resolve, I don't see the problem here and why shouldn't this be marked as duplicate? Prove me wrong and I will change my mind.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve merge conflicts in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-to-resolve-merge-conflicts-in-git)

Comment: How can I have conflict on my own files when I already committed those changes?

Comment: I pushed the last commit and merge it with remote master. It went well. Then now when I started working on the same files and did a commit, tried to merge it with changes from remote master, I get conflict on my own branch files. No one did any changes there except me.

Comment: This sounds very strange and hard to believe, however, I will wait for more experienced to come along. I don't think this is possible (as you are describing it) but lets see...